# Connect to bigquery from databricks using sparklyr

Tags: r, google-bigquery, databricks, sparkr, sparklyr

I'm pretty new to **databricks**. I have it running with **Gloogle Cloud**.

I have been able to connect to **bigquery** where I have my tables, and bring some data using `SparkR`:

```
library(SparkR)

sparkR.session()

df <- loadDF(
  path = "project_id.dataset_id.table_id",
  source = "bigquery",
  header = "true",
  inferSchema = "true"
)
```

This works and returns a SparkDataFrame:

```
df
SparkDataFrame[variable:string, position:bigint, label:string, measurement_level:string, wave_id:bigint, country_id:bigint]
```

I'm trying to do it using `sparklyr` but something is not working:

```
library(sparklyr)


sc <- spark_connect(method  = "databricks")
df <- spark_read_bigquery(
  sc,
  name = "my_table",
  projectId = project_id
  datasetId = dataset_id,
  tableId = table_id
)
```

This returns an error:

```
com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException:
Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in
entry: bq.staging_dataset.gcs_bucket=null at
com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConnectorModule.provideSparkBigQueryConfig(SparkBigQueryConnectorModule.java:65)
while locating com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig

1 error

Run `sparklyr::spark_last_error()` to see the full Spark error (multiple lines)
To use the previous style of error message set
`options("sparklyr.simple.errors" = TRUE)`
```

I can see that `bq.staging_dataset.gcs_bucket=null`. Does it mean it is not finding the bucket? I has worked with `SparkR` though.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you set `bigquery_defaults()`? [function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparkbq/versions/0.1.1/topics/bigquery_defaults)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to do for your sparklyr connection to work:

1. Add `library(sparkbq)` to your code. You might have to install it, because does not come preinstalled by default on databricks clusters.
2. Set the bigquery defaults with `sparkbq::bigquery_defaults()`. Your error says that you didn't specify a `gcsBucket` to store temporary files. You will also need to specify a `serviceAccountKeyFile`, `datasetLocation` ("US" or "EU") and `type` ("direct" and "avro" are preferable).

You probably are not a GCP admin, so go to the GCP console and navigate to Buckets, which you can do by typing in the search bar. There you can select a bucket and copy its name. Analogously, navigate to Service Accounts, select and click on an account and copy/paste its ID.

Your code should look like this:

```r
install.packages("sparkbq")
library(sparklyr)
library(sparkbq)

sc <- spark_connect(method  = "databricks")

# Set BigQuery defaults
bigquery_defaults(
  billingProjectId = project_id,
  gcsBucket = "your-preferred-gcs-bucket",
  datasetLocation = "US",
  serviceAccountKeyFile = "service-account-id",
  type = "direct"
)

my_table <- spark_read_bigquery(
  sc,
  name = "my_table",
  projectId = project_id
  datasetId = dataset_id,
  tableId = table_id
)
```

Finally, in [the docs of spark_read_bigquery()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparkbq/versions/0.1.1/topics/spark_read_bigquery) you can find a similar example with explanation of the arguments passed to bigquery_defaults.